# Set start height for a text box but resize when the window expand

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a problem with my current code.
I have this:

```html
 <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Text editor -->
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Margin="3" MaxHeight="500" Padding="2" x:Name="TextEditor" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" KeyDown="TextEditor_KeyDown" />

                <!-- Tools buttons -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <!-- Save button -->
                    <Button Width="27" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="button_textEditor_save" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="button_textEditor_save_Click" >
                        <Image Source="Assets/Images/save_file.png"/>
                    </Button>

                    <!-- Open button -->
                    <Button Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="button_textEditor_open" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="button_textEditor_save_Click" >
                        <Image Source="Assets/Images/open_file.png"/>
                    </Button>

                    <!-- Save location -->

                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

with this code, I get this window:

[Not resized window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzaaj.png)

And when I maximize the window, i get this:
[Window maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGYMq.png)

So, now, my question is, how I can set an initial size for the text box (I know height parameter but with this , the control will not expand when I maximize the window), I'm working in a window with this size: 650x900. If I use a grid to set the text box (Right now StackPanel) I have to set specific sizes to the grid's rows. I hope I have explained correctly. Thanks

Comment: if you use grid you can make 2 rows and set `*` height for TextBox row and `Auto` for buttons panel to make TextBox grow after window resize

Answer (score 0):

when you place any control within grid with row and column defined, 
control has Grid.Row = 0 and Grid.Column=0 value by default. Here in your code the first StakePlane also has default row and column value 0. If you comment out column definition and try then you will find that the Textbox is getting resized with window being resized

Comment: All is contained in the first control, that is a StackPanel. If you want the full code: https://pastebin.com/drMLNaHf  Now, I want to set a initial height for the text box (It will be a mini text editor), because I don't want to see: http://i.imgur.com/e94DXE5.png . When I start to write, the lines are adding, and the text box is expanded. But, I want a initial height, for example the full space until the bottom buttons reach the end. As I said above, if I set the textbox height to 250 (for example) when I maximize the window It will not expand to the bottom.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me. But as you are saying you want text editor type thing, you can try like this:

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear to me. But as you are saying you want text editor type thing, you can try like this:

```
 <Grid>
        <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <!--<RowDefinition Height="*" />-->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Text editor -->
        <!--<StackPanel>-->
            <TextBox  Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" MaxHeight="500" Padding="2" x:Name="TextEditor" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" KeyDown="TextEditor_KeyDown" />

            <!-- Tools buttons -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">

                <!-- Save button -->
                <Button Width="27" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="button_textEditor_save" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="button_textEditor_save_Click" >
                    <Image Source="Assets/Images/save_file.png"/>
                </Button>

                <!-- Open button -->
                <Button Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="button_textEditor_open" Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="button_textEditor_save_Click" >
                    <Image Source="Assets/Images/open_file.png"/>
                </Button>

                <!-- Save location -->

            </StackPanel>
        <!--</StackPanel>-->
    </Grid>
```

you can also checkout these links - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) and [wpftutorial](https://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html)

Comment: I used your code but I do not get what I want. So, see it.

Comment: I used your code but I do not get what I want. So, see it. I want to get this: http://i.imgur.com/PEJKFP8.png (not maximized window) and http://i.imgur.com/5RfaojE.png (maximized window size). Now you're wondering, how did you do that? Simply I added lines to get this result. I did it just to show you. With your code I got this: http://i.imgur.com/v4Gd2EM.png (not maximized window) and the maximized window http://i.imgur.com/VSGrowR.png ,I remarked the TextBox here so you can see that with the width it works (Colum definitions). The text box width expands depending on the window size

Comment: See it. With this code: https://pastebin.com/XYVKpdr8 The textbox height is expanded to 200 (How the row height is defined), but If I maximize the window It is not expand. IMG: http://i.imgur.com/FF5mFjz.png

Comment: @TomasWegenast have you got solution? I have checked your code. You have set the row height explicitly to 200. That is why Text-box is not expanding when window is maximised. change your row definition to following and try

`<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition  />
<RowDefinition Height="auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>`